# Obtener consulta SQL con cantidades por fecha más reciente en varias zonas

Tags: sql, ms-access

Tengo una tabla con los campos **FECHA**,**CODIGO**,**ZONA** y **CANTIDAD**. Estoy intentando sacar una consulta en la que se muestren únicamente cantidades de cada zona en la fecha más reciente. El problema es que la fecha no tiene por qué ser la misma en todas las zonas y no consigo montar la query correctamente, pues sólo consigo mostrar los datos de la zona cuya fecha es la más reciente.

Es decir, si tengo datos de la zona SILO del 20/10 y datos de la zona CARGA del 25/10 sólo consigo mostrar los datos de la zona CARGA del 25/10... Y necesito los datos más recientes para cada ZONA creada.

Esta es la consulta que tengo montada hasta ahora. Está montada en un Access 2016:

```
SELECT recuentos.FECHA, materiales.descripcion, materiales.codigo, recuentos.ZONA
FROM recuentos INNER JOIN materiales ON recuentos.CODIGO = materiales.codigo
WHERE (((recuentos.FECHA) In (SELECT max(FECHA) FROM recuentos)));
```

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Gracias.

Edito para añadir más info:

Estoy montando la query con una subconsulta pero obtengo un error de sintáxis en la operación JOIN. Pruebo en Access y se me queda subrayado la palabra recuentos, al comienzo del SELECT:

```
SELECT Vista.ULT, Vista.ZONA, recuentos.CODIGO, materiales.descripcion, recuentos.CANTIDAD 
FROM ((SELECT Max(recuentos.FECHA) AS ULT, recuentos.ZONA FROM recuentos GROUP BY recuentos.ZONA) AS Vista INNER JOIN materiales ON recuentos.CODIGO = materiales.codigo) 
GROUP BY Vista.ZONA, recuentos.CODIGO, materiales.descripcion, recuentos.CANTIDAD;
```

Comment: En SQL standard la query sería Select max(recuentos.Fecha, .... from.... group by materiales.descripcion, materiales.codigo, recuentos.zona. En access debiera de ser igual [group by](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/access/concepts/structured-query-language/group-by-clause-microsoft-access-sql)

Comment: Gracias, voy a hacerlo como comentas y actualizo aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vale, pues he encontrado la solución.

```
SELECT Max(Vista.ULT) AS ULT_FE, Vista.ZONA, recuentos.CODIGO, materiales.descripcion, recuentos.CANTIDAD
FROM ((SELECT Max(recuentos.FECHA) AS ULT, recuentos.ZONA FROM recuentos GROUP BY recuentos.ZONA)  AS Vista INNER JOIN recuentos ON Vista.ZONA=recuentos.ZONA) INNER JOIN materiales ON recuentos.CODIGO = materiales.codigo
GROUP BY Vista.ZONA, recuentos.CODIGO, materiales.descripcion, recuentos.CANTIDAD;
```

El problema estaba el primer campo del SELECT que tenía que ser: **Max(Vista.ULT) AS ULT_FE** en lugar de **Vista.ULT**.